# Right speaker doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, sound, windows-7, asus

I use K53SD Asus laptop with dual boot (win 7 - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
When ı use ubuntu , left speaker work normally but right speaker doesn't work .
When ı use win 7 left speaker work normally again also right speaker work but less voice.

I make a search about my problem but none of them didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If it doesn't work on both OS's, I'd suspect a hardware issue. Make sure the right speaker is plugged correctly. If possible, also attach it to another audio source, like a mobile phone and check or testwise exchange cables.

Comment: in the beginning , I suspected a hardware issue but right speaker work with   less voice  on win 7 .

Comment: Still, please try with another audio source, if possible.

Comment: unfortunately , it is almost impossible for me .

Comment: Sound troubleshoot step will help you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: @vembutech thanks for  answer's  but none of them didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this tool and play with it. It will help:

type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

but you likely have a hardware problem.

After installing this tool you have to see with of the applications in this collection, will work for you, and when you open an application you have to play around with it to see if it will fix the problem or not, all of them have a restore option so don't be afraid.

this is a list of apps that will be installed, to open one of them copy paste it to terminal:

echomixer, envy24control, hdajackretask, hdspconf, hdspmixer, rmedigicontrol

with this app you can remap your speakers so to work correctly...

Comment: Please be more specific: What is the OP to do after executing this command? What does it actually do? It may seem trivial for experienced Linux users, but please don't forget that there are Linux newbies out there who have no idea what this answer actually says.